# Auth0 embedded login flow

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, auth0, auth0-lock, auth0-connection

We are trying to implement Auth0 in our next+fastify based application. The login page is custom and we want to integrate the login using the [embedded](https://auth0.com/docs/login/embedded-login) login from the fastify server.
I am naive to oAuth and Auth0, I have a few doubts around it:

1. How do we verify the token? Do we verify the JWT and maintain the token on or fastify server or should we always the validate the token on Auth0 endpoint? I tried calling the [userinfo](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#get-user-info) endpoint which resulted in rate limiting. So, I interpret if we just verify the JWT on server instead of sending to Auth0 server. Also we send and maintain the JWT in cookies to validate the client always. Is the understading correct?
2. Is embedded login safe enough to be used in production? Are there any risk associated around it?
3. Is the approach correct? Is there any alternative way to implement the login flow? We also need to integrate reset password and rest of the functionality. I have read the SDK docs and it seems to have support for all.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2):

1. There are several options to validate a token issued by auth0, they recommend you to take advantage of middleware to verify the token. Multiple frameworks have their own middleware to check and validate JWT. It's as easy as integrate middleware with your application and perform validation when you need it. Check this:

https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/json-web-tokens/validate-json-web-tokens

2. In my opinion, it is always better to go with the Universal Login option of auth0, since embedded login sometimes incur into the cross origin authentication issue. Remember, when a user tries to log into your application using auth0, it redirects the user to another domain that differs from the one serving your application. In my experience, using the universal login provides you more information about the login process of your users, and that makes the process of debugging errors and auth processes easier. You can read more about login with auth0 here:

https://auth0.com/docs/login/embedded-login

https://auth0.com/docs/login/embedded-login/cross-origin-authentication

3. Yep, you can integrate the reset password process, which is almost entirely handled by auth0 itself. As I said earlier, we use Universal Login for our applications since it provides more control over the authentication flow. That doesn't mean you can't use Embedded login, it is a very good option too, but it seems more focused in UX rather than control auth flow.

Check this link if you still have doubts about the best approach: https://auth0.com/docs/universal-login/universal-vs-embedded-login

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtHwLH_P2ZY

Explained much better here